# remove an element that created

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a text input and when you write a text and press enter key, then text input be clear and add that text below with close anchor link as a label.
i want when i click on close link, that label removed. remove code commented
on js code.

```js
var itemsArray = [];
        $("#Label").on("keydown", function(e) {
            var contentHtml = "";
            var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
            if (code == 13) { //Enter keycode
                itemsArray.push($("#Label").val());
                for (let i = 0; i < itemsArray.length; i++) {
                    if (itemsArray[i] != '') {
                        contentHtml += '<div class="dib w-auto m-1 p-0"><div class="d-flex bg-dark text-secondary p-1 rounded"><span class="h-half mb-1">' + itemsArray[i] + '</span> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="remover badge badge-dark mt-1 ml-2 mb-1 rounded-circle">×</a></div></div>';
                    }
                }
                $("#labels-box").html(contentHtml);
                $("#Label").val('');
            }
        });
        /// i want to remove labels with this code
        const items = document.querySelectorAll('a.remover');
        items.forEach(itm => itm.addEventListener('click', function() {
            console.log(itm);
        }));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 class="pt-4">Add New Anime</h3>
                <hr>
                <form name="articleForm">
                    <div class="row m-0 p-0">
                        <div class="col-md-8 mt-0 mb-0 mx-auto p-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Photo</label>
                                    <input type="file" id="files" name="files" single accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif, image/jpg" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8 mt-0 mb-0 mx-auto p-2">
                            <div class="form-group m-0">
                                <label class="control-label">Title</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8 mt-0 mb-0 mx-auto p-2">
                            <div class="form-group m-0">
                                <label class="control-label">Summery</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" name="summery" id="summery" cols="30" rows="7"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8 mt-0 mb-0 mx-auto p-2">
                            <div class="form-group m-0">
                                <label class="control-label">Label</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Label" id="Label" />
                                <div class="dib w-100 pt-2 pb-3 m-0" id="labels-box">

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8 mt-0 mb-0 mx-auto p-2">
                            <div class="form-group text-center m-0">
                                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-info pr-5 pl-5">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: Please add your markup as well and create a snippet

Comment: i cannot understand. what?

Comment: Add the corresponding HTML code so that we can see a demo right here on SO. You can create a snippet by clicking on the `<>` button in your question box.

Comment: You need to prevent the default behaviour of the browser when pressing enter on that label field. Right now you don't do that and we can't test your snippet because your content disappears from the page on enter.

Answer (score 1):

You can move the removing logic inside `keydown` event, consider the following (I've added a `jquery` implementation too):

```js
var itemsArray = [];
$("#Label").on("keydown", function(e) {
  var contentHtml = "";
  var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
  if (code == 13) { //Enter keycode
    itemsArray.push($("#Label").val());
    for (let i = 0; i < itemsArray.length; i++) {
      if (itemsArray[i] != '') {
        contentHtml += '<div class="dib w-auto m-1 p-0"><div class="d-flex bg-dark text-secondary p-1 rounded"><span class="h-half mb-1">' + itemsArray[i] + '</span> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="remover badge badge-dark mt-1 ml-2 mb-1 rounded-circle">×</a></div></div>';
      }
    }
    $("#labels-box").html(contentHtml);
    $("#Label").val('');
    /*
    const items = document.querySelectorAll('a.remover');
    items.forEach(itm => itm.addEventListener('click', function() {
      //console.log(itm);
      $(itm).closest("div.dib").remove()
    }));
    
    */
    $("a.remover").on("click", function() {
      $(this).closest("div.dib").remove()
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="Label" />
<div id="labels-box">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right, in the first place you append that input content on enter press.

Then, you want that when clicking the link removal button to remove the link, right?

If that's what you want, this might help you:

```
$("body").on("click", "a.remover", function(){
    var index = $(this).index();
    if(index !== -1){
        items.splice(index, 1);
    }

    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: When using the solution it's best to do the event delegation from the closest static parent instead of the body.

Comment: yes but if i want to remove 3th element, what i do now?
and that element must be removed from itemArray.